# Remove all text before last / and all text after : and remove the : from a list

Tags: sed, rsync

```
name//name/20000_random_test.txt: No space left on device
```

This is an example of a line I need to modify in a file with all lines with the same pattern as follows:

```
name//name/<nameoffile>: No space left on device
```

I tried using:

```
cat didnotmakeit.txt | sed 's|.*\\\(.*\)|\1|' > filestoupload.txt
```

and

```
sed 's|.*\\\(.*\)|\1|' didnotmakeit.txt > filestoupload.txt
```

But none of these did anything to the file.

A certain amount of files did not transfer to a folder because it ran out of space. I copied and pasted the list in a file.

I need to remove the characters before and after the file name. This way, I will have a list to then use another command something like:

```
grep NAME_REGEXP /path/to/filenames.list | rsync -a --files-from - . remote.example.com:
```

Please help me remove these unnecessary characters. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work :

```
sed 's!.*/\([^:].*\):.*!\1!' didnotmakeit.txt
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!